# cudaMemcpy not copying any data

Tags: cuda

I use the cuda-gdb to check values of dcost and find that no copying was done by cudaMemcpy even though it returns `cudaSuccess`.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdint.h>

int main(){
int64_t nvtx_scale = ((int64_t)1)<<14;

uint64_t* cost = (uint64_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint64_t)*nvtx_scale);

for(int64_t i=0; i < nvtx_scale; i++)
    cost[i] = uint64_t(-1);

uint64_t* dcost;
cudaMalloc(&dcost, nvtx_scale*sizeof(uint64_t));

cudaError_t err;

err = cudaMemcpy(dcost, cost, sizeof(uint64_t)*nvtx_scale, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
return 0;
}
```

Has this got anything to do with the fact that I set
`CUDA_DEBUGGER_SOFTWARE_PREEMPTION=1` as suggested in the cuda-gdb documentation to allow debugging with the same gpu without stopping the display manager?

Comment: Unless you can show a short, complete code which reproduces the problem, I don't believe anyone can tell you what might be going wrong

Comment: @talonmies done : i have done nothing else that's y i didn't feel the need to add the complete code

Comment: You say that the code you posted doesn't copy any data. But how do you know that? I see nothing in that code which would confirm that the copy did or did not work

Comment: @talonmies As i said in the question, i used cuda-gdb to check the values in dcost by placing a break point after cudaMemcpy, no copying happened the values were still all zero

Comment: You also said in the question that you are doing computations, and there isn't anything like that in the repro code either. The code you posted works and you can probably confirm that yourself by copying some values back from GPU and printing those out. If that doesn't work I would question whether you have a working CUDA installation or not

Comment: @talonmies By Computation i just meant the uint64_t(-1) part, but it still doesn't show, since it works in your pc, i guess i should check my cuda installation

Comment: There may be a usage error here as well.  I don't think the print command in cuda-gdb can be used to display the contents of a device variable while stepping through host code.  I believe it is necessary to be *stopped in device (kernel) code* before the print command can be used to display the contents of data on the device.  Presumably you are using the print command (a cuda-gdb session output would have been a useful addition to your question) to display variables.  Since your posted code has no device kernels, you could not have been in device code.

Comment: Try creating a simple kernel, add it to your code, set a breakpoint in the kernel, then try inspecting device memory.  You may also want to look at [this question and the upvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683721/check-global-device-memory-using-cuda-gdb).

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks a lot you were right i checked the values from inside a kernel and they were correct, i didn't know that you couldn't check device variables inside host code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following slightly modified version of your code:

```
#include<stdint.h>
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    int64_t nvtx_scale = ((int64_t)1)<<14;

    uint64_t* cost = (uint64_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint64_t)*nvtx_scale);

    for(int64_t i=0; i < nvtx_scale; i++)
        cost[i] = uint64_t(123456789);

    uint64_t* dcost;
    cudaMalloc(&dcost, nvtx_scale*sizeof(uint64_t));
    cudaMemcpy(dcost, cost, sizeof(uint64_t)*nvtx_scale, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    memset(cost, 0, sizeof(uint64_t)*nvtx_scale);
    cudaMemcpy(cost, dcost, sizeof(uint64_t)*nvtx_scale, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        std::cout << i << " " << cost[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

compiles and runs for me like this:

```
C:\Users\talonmies>nvcc cudacopy.cu
cudacopy.cu
   Creating library a.lib and object a.exp

C:\Users\talonmies>cuda-memcheck a.exe
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
0 123456789
1 123456789
2 123456789
3 123456789
4 123456789
5 123456789
6 123456789
7 123456789
8 123456789
9 123456789
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

If you cannot reproduce this, you have a problem with your CUDA installation.

Comment: You are right i am able to reproduce this, the problem is in cuda-gdb i am printing the value of dcost[0] and it shows 0, i have no idea why this is happening can you try using the cuda debugger to print the value of dcost after cudaMemcpy, thanks anyway